# How to make my java program print the smallest and largest numbers from the values i input

Tags: java, algorithm, numbers

I need java to ask for an int type input and then print it out immediately after and keep asking for numbers until a sentinel is entered to tell the program to stop asking for numbers. Once the program stops asking for numbers, I need it to print out the smallest number and the largest number out of that set of numbers I've typed in, however I cannot use an array or anything of that sort because I need to make a method to execute this operation. I have only been doing java for 2-3 months now so I'm basically a beginner.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot pass an array into a method for processing?

Comment: Actually you can pass an array to function I don't know why you say I can't use array?

Comment: Why would you need an array to store two values? `int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;` then `int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;` when you get input from the user (say `n`), then `max = Math.max(max, n)` and `min = Math.min(min, n)` should do it.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a homework. So would not give you the exact solution. But you can try something like this:

```
 //declare two variables
 private static int max = 0;
 private static int min = 0;
```

Now inside your main method as you keep entering the integers you can compare and replace the values

```
  if (yourEnteredVariable > max){
      max =  yourEnteredVariable;
  }

  if (yourEnteredVariable < min){
     min =  yourEnteredVariable;
  }
```

You can have the above clauses in separate methods.

Comment: better to initialize `max = Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `min = Integer.MAX_VALUE` in my opinion.